# akka unstashAll not working

Tags: scala, akka

I am implementing an actor with multiple states and using `Stash` not to lose any messages. My states are initializing (get something from DB), running (handling requests) and updating (updating my state).
My problem is that I lose the messages when i try to `unstashAll()` in future resolving.

```
def initializing: Receive = {
case Initialize =>
  log.info("initializing")
  (for {
    items1 <- db.getItems("1")
    items2 <- db.getItems("2")
  } yield items1 ::: items2) map {items => 
    unstashAll()
    context.become(running(items))
  }
case r =>
  log.debug(s"actor received message: $r while initializing and stashed it for further processing")
  stash()}
```

i fixed it by changing my implementation to this

```
def initializing: Receive = {
case Initialize =>
  log.info("initializing")
  (for {
    items1 <- db.getItems("1")
    items2 <- db.getItems("2")
  } yield items1 ::: items2) pipeTo self
  context.become({
    case items: List[Item] =>
      unstashAll()
      context.become(running(items))
    case r =>
      log.debug(s"actor received message: $r while initializing and stashed it for further processing")
      stash()
  })
case r =>
  log.debug(s"actor received message: $r while initializing and stashed it for further processing")
  stash()}
```

can anyone explain why the first didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `unstashAll` part works fine. The problem is that you were running it  - together with your `context.become` - as part of a future callback.

This means that the code inside your `map` block escapes the predictability of your actor sequential processing. In other words, this could happen:

1. you call `unstashAll`
2. your messages are put back in the actor's mailbox
3. the actor picks up your messages one by one. The context still hasn't changed, so they are stashed again
4. your context finally becomes `running` (but it's too late)

The solution is - as you found out - the `pipeTo` pattern, which essentially sends a `Future`s result to the actor as a message. This makes it all sequential and predictable.